# Regex capturing string between two different headers

Tags: python, regex

I'm sure this has been answered in a different context.

Basically, I have a comment box and wish to extract the comment header as well as the text below it.

The comment box looks like this:

**[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/01]:** Here is
my comment  and the comment continues on this line
and this line

**[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/02]:** Here is
my second comment  and the comment continues on this line
and this line

**userid, 8/12/2019:** Here is
my second comment  and the comment continues on this line
and this line

**[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/02]:** Here is
my third comment  and the comment continues on this line
and this line
blah blah

**userid, 8/12/2019:** Here is
comment
more comments

---

Essentially, there are two headers:

**[userid-systemid add comment 2019/01/02]:**

AND

**userid, 8/12/2019:**

followed by the comment that spans on multiple lines until the next header. Note that **userid** and **systemid** are user names of variable length.

What I've managed so far:

**Attempt 1:**

```
([a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:|\[.*\]:)(.*)
```

Great, this captures the headers (which need to be captured) and the comment on the **same** line, but now need their respective comment that continues below. Perhaps positive lookahead for next header?

```
([a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:)(.|\n)*?(?=[a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:|\[.*\])|(\[.*\]:)(.|\n)*?(?=[a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:|\[.*\]:)|([a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:)(?s)(.*)|(\[.*\]:)(?s)(.*)
```

More readable (separated by '|' at each partition):

```
([a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:)(.|\n)*?(?=[a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:|\[.*\])|
(\[.*\]:)(.|\n)*?(?=[a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:|\[.*\]:)|
([a-z]+, [\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}:)(?s)(.*)|
(\[.*\]:)(?s)(.*)
```

This works. Somehow. Basically, it's a combination regex:

```
<header1> 
comment 
<header1 OR header>

<header2> 
comment 
<header1 OR header>

<header1> comment  

<header2> comment
```

However, I find it completely redundant in some areas and would to perhaps improve it a bit and make it more concise. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you wish to capture the dates, headers and comments. Maybe, this expression or some similar expression might be working then OK:

```
(\[?[a-z\s,-]+(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})\]?)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=[\r\n]\[[a-z]|[a-z]+,|$)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OvpsHj/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(\[?[a-z\s,-]+(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})\]?)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=[\r\n]\[[a-z]|[a-z]+,|$)"

test_str = """
[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/01]: Here is
my comment and the comment continues on this line
and this line

[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/02]: Here is
my second comment and the comment continues on this line
and this line

userid, 8/12/2019: Here is
my second comment and the comment continues on this line
and this line

[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/02]: Here is
my third comment and the comment continues on this line
and this line
blah blah

userid, 8/12/2019: Here is
comment
more comments

"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

```
[('[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/01]', '2019/01/01', 'Here is\nmy comment and the comment continues on this line\nand this line\n\n'), ('[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/02]', '2019/01/02', 'Here is\nmy second comment and the comment continues on this line\nand this line\n\n'), ('userid, 8/12/2019', '8/12/2019', 'Here is\nmy second comment and the comment continues on this line\nand this line\n\n'), ('[userid-systemid added comment 2019/01/02]', '2019/01/02', 'Here is\nmy third comment and the comment continues on this line\nand this line\nblah blah\n\n'), ('userid, 8/12/2019', '8/12/2019', 'Here is\ncomment\nmore comments\n')]
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/daVhke/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/daVhke/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I can see how this works, only problem is that 'userid' and 'systemid' are not fixed. They are of variable length. Let me play around with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could match either starting with an opening and a closing square bracket that contains a date like pattern at the end or match starting with 1+ word chars, a comma and a date like pattern.

In the example data, there are different formats for the date. To match a date like pattern inside the square brackets, perhaps just matching digits with a forward slash can make it unique enough for a match.

Repeat matching all the lines that follow that do not start with one of the patterns that identify a header.

```
^((?:\[[^]]*\d+/\d+/\d+\]|\w+,[ \t]*\d+/\d+/\d+):)(.*(?:\r?\n(?!(?:\[[^]]*\d+/\d+/\d+\]|\w+,[ \t]*\d+/\d+/\d+)).*)*)
```

**Pattern parts**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\[[^]]*\d+/\d+/\d+\]` Match `[`...`]` with date like format
    - `|` Or
    - `\w+,[ \t]*\d+/\d+/\d+` 1+ word chars, comma and date like format
  - `):` Close non capturing group
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match any char except a newline
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\r?\n` Match newline
    - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

      - `(?:\[[^]]*\d+/\d+/\d+\]|\w+,[ \t]*\d+/\d+/\d+)` Match a starting pattern
    - `)` Close lookahead
    - `.*` Match any char except a newline
  - `)*` close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qddXgQ/1)